# Activate text to speech

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to activate text to speech in Google hangouts in my nexus 5 phone so that messages can be read aloud . I couldn't figure it out. Please guide me. 
Can this service be used in Gmail and whatsapp. If yes then how

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and no answers have been voted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you talking about [TalkBack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback), the accessibility program that comes with a lot of Android devices.

In order to activate TalkBack (assuming it is installed), open your phone settings, then go to the Accessibility section. Select TalkBack and enable it (and accept the warning that TalkBack will be able to see sensitive information).

After it is enabled, you should look through the settings for TalkBack and configure it to your needs.

Comment: Stephen is wrong in a way, Actually Talkback is for differently abled people, or the one's weak at vision, it will read out loud everything, its not what the questioner means. It will not specifically read out elements, and that would be very irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Install Hancent but retain Hangout as the default SMS app.You'll get incoming text in both apps but you'll get nice text to speech in your Bluetooth earpiece when connected.